# Make rectangle diagonal div using css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I want to make a rectangle div (as shown below behind the video) and rotate to 35 degrees using CSS.
And I want to make it responsive.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `transform: rotate(35deg)`

```css
.rect {
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,255,0,1), rgba(0,255,0,0.3));
  transform: rotate(35deg) translate(-10px, 100px);
  border-radius: 0 0 50px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="rect"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you Ibram, It's working fine. but If I rotate to 157 deg
 for ex: 
transform: translate(4%,10px) rotate(157deg); It's increases the screen width and content goes outside of screen size.
Is there any way I can fit into the screen size?

Comment: @kinaligandhi Either use `position: absolute` or use a container that applies an overflow-property e.g. `overflow: hidden`

Comment: kinaligandhi  please update the  question  with  the code you try to do to get more help ... but in general you can try the solution offered be @F.Müller it will work fine if you need to hide any ship outside screen

Comment: Thank you so much for your response @IbramReda. It's working as expected.